# Include gltf-pipeline into browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify, cesiumjs

I browserified gltf-pipeline via wzrd.in (https://wzrd.in/standalone/gltf-pipeline@latest). Unfortunately I am not able to import it into my react app.

I tried:

```
const gltfPipeline = require('./Converter/gltf-pipeline')

import gltfPipeline from './Converter/gltf-pipeline'

import * as gltfPipeline from './Converter/gltf-pipeline'
```

But I receive an error:

```
./src/Components/Page/Models/Converter/gltf-pipeline.js
  Line 1:1:         Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 1:124:       'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:135:       'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 1:242:       Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 1:247:       Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:112:       Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:2623:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:2944:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:2973:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:4581:      Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:4586:      Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:4738:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:4909:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:5196:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:5861:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:8898:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:9718:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:11007:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:11298:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:11303:     Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:11428:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
...
```

Any idea how to solve this?